# How to add App to Sencha Themer

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha 6.5.0, Sencha Themer v1.2.0.41 on macOS 10.12.5 . I follow official tutorial video, I stuck at this step.

[image]

How to add an app to Sencha Themer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug inside Sencha Themer v1.2.0.41 . Sencha team confirmed about the bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your theme in your app where all the themes are placed. In my case it is My App's workspace > packages > local > My-Theme.

Comment: It is a bug inside Sencha Themer v1.2.0.41 . Sencha team confirmed about the bug.

Comment: Do Nhu Vy can you comment on this issue if you have any idea.

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208670/sencha-themer-scss-resource-integration-issue