# Sencha Themer SCSS resource Integration Issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd5

I am getting stuck with an issue, i have created a theme with Sencha themer and its integrating well with Architect. But, if we add a SCSS file for putting custom SCSS then that changes are on reflected in my application.

**Sencha Architect Version: 4.2
Themer: v1.2.0.41**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence clearly: `add a SCSS file for putting custom SCSS then that changes are on reflected in my application.` .Notice `*.scss` **must be compiled, then you will see result**.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I mean any SCSS resource added in theme(created by Themer ) in architect is not merged in the main css file after publishing.
It will be great if we can connect over Skype or Mail as we are stuck in some major issue. skype: nitin.sharma964